# Should "magic" getter functions be used for dynamically calculated values or just existing properties?

Tags: object-oriented, php, programming-practices, methods, properties

For example, if I had a `Customer` class and wanted to get all orders by them. Would it be better to do:

```
class Customer{
    public function getOrders(){
        return results from db query
    }
}

...

foreach($customer->getOrders()){}
```

or

```
class Customer{
    private function getOrders(){
        return results from db query
    }

    public function __get($attribute){
        if($attribute === 'orders'){
            return $this->getOrders();
        }
    }
}

...

foreach($customer->orders){}
```

The former isn't as bloated, but then it's nice to be able to access it as if it were a property rather than with `getOrders()`.

Comment: what programming language is this, [tag:php]?

Comment: PHP yes, although it would be applicable to all programming languages, no?

Comment: Only if returning results from the db query is a fast and cheap operation.

Comment: ...which it generally isn't considered to be for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The `__get` magic method is completely fine, just make sure to couple it either with the `@property` (if you want a magic `__set` as well) or `@property-read` [phpDoc annotation](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html) so consumers of your class know what they can expect from the public API of your class.

PHP's combination of `__get` and `__set` methods and the `@property` annotation is a poor-man's version of C#'s attributes and just like in C#, they're not bad as long as you show in the API of the class what the class actually offers (in C# you don't need the annotation for this, because the language supports attributes by default).

I personally don't use magic `__set` at all, but have been using `__get` to a great extent and have never had problems with the method.